# Deserialization of stream using System.Text in .net core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I have a dumb question, but I dont know how to solve it.

```
List<Currency> currencies = new List<Currency>();
var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
currencies = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(responseStream, Currency);
```

red line below Currency - currency is a type which is noit valid in a given context.

I tried typeof(Currency), also, new Currency() and nothjing.. Im aware that I need to pass a return type of model.

Comment: currencies = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Currency>>(responseStream); // try this

Comment: And there's no need to allocate a `new List<Currency>();` beforehand either, just do `var currencies = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Currency>>(responseStream);`